# Isotypic component of class $\mathfrak d$

Tags: representation-theory, topological-groups, automorphic-forms

I am reading through *Representations of $\mathfrak p$-adic groups* (P. Cartier, Corvallis proceedings Vol I) and had a question about the following section.  $G$ is a topological group of totally disconnected type.

[image]

I'm confused on the definition of the space $V_{\mathfrak d}$.  Isn't a "minimal $K$-invariant subspace of $V$ affording a representation of $K$ of class $\mathfrak d$" nothing more than an isomorphic copy of $\mathfrak d$ occuring as a $K$-invariant subspace of $V$?

Comment: It seems the isotypic component of $\mathfrak d$ (irreducible) refers to the $n$ isomorphic copies of $\mathfrak d$ in $V$

Comment: A semisimple rep decomposes as a direct sum of irreps, but noncanonically. However, if we sum all the irreps of a given isomorphism class, we get an *isotypic component*, which *is* canonical. It contains all irreps of a given isoclass (being the span of them), and doesn't contain any irrep of a different type. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Feel free to post this as an answer, I will accept it.